# Redirect all POST / GET requests on nginx server to another domain

Tags: nginx, redirect

My goal is to redirect all API requests (both GET or POST) from `old-domain.com` to `new-domain.com` but only from specific GET `company_id` value (`ABC`). We will still treat other requests other than that to `old-domain.com`.

For example :

`old-domain.com/user/view/123?company_id=ABC`

will be redirected to

`new-domain.com/user/view/123?company_id=ABC`.

But, I need all requests to these URLS to not be redirected.

```
old-domain.com/user/view/123?company_id=XYZ
old-domain.com/user/view/123
old-domain.com/other/api/as/well
```

Here is what I have made so far.

```
if ($arg_company_id = ABC) {
    return 302 https://new-domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

All is working well but I face another issue. I also need to redirect all POST requests as well.

```
old-domain.com/user/update/123?company_id=XYZ
POST variables : name=John, phone_number=555123
```

The above request will only redirect the request, but not the POST data (the `name=John, phone_number=555123` data is not sent to the new domain).

I have read about `proxy_pass` but that way is not working for a different domain.

I hope I can get some enlightment. Thank you.

**UPDATE** :
Thank you to Ivan's answer. I modify my conf to this (nginx doesn't support nested-if):

```
    set $RR "";

    if ($arg_company_id = ABC) {
        set $RR R;
    }

    if ($request_method = GET) {
        set $RR "${RR}G";
    }

    if ($request_method = POST) {
        set $RR "${RR}P";
    }

    if ($RR = RG){
       return 302 https://new-domain.com$request_uri;
    }

    if ($RR = RP) {
        return 307 https://new-domain$request_uri;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [HTTP 307](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/307) redirect, it should keep POST request body:

```
if ($arg_company_id = ABC) {
    if ($request_method = GET) {
        return 302 https://new-domain.com$request_uri;
    }
    if ($request_method = POST) {
        return 307 https://new-domain.com$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! You just give me an idea. I will update my question.

Comment: Hey ! You are what I call a life saver.